# Error in aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe:

```
head(df)
     Year          Find             Found
6982 1901          267              246
6983 1901          271              251
6984 1902          317              236
6985 1903          339              244
6986 1904          339              260
6987 1903          345              15
5255 1902           47              45
5256 1901           46              NA
5257 1906           45              150
5258 1905           42              24
5259 1910           42              78
5260 1910           41              NA
```

When I am trying to aggregate it:

```
aggdata <-aggregate(df, by=list(Year), 
                  FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get an `error`

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(AndelKvinnorUttax, by = list(Year), FUN = sum,  : 
  object 'Year' not found
```

I can´t find the problem...

My `solution` is:

```
aggr=cbind(aggregate(data=df,Find~Year,
           FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE),aggregate(data=df,Found~Year,
           FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE))[,c(1,2,4)]
```

Anyone?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` doesn't automatically evaluate `Year` in the scope of the `data.frame` in the `data` argument. You have to tell it explicitly where to find `Year`, i.e....

```
aggdata <-aggregate(df, by=list(df$Year), 
                  FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
#  Group.1 Year Find Found
#1    1901 5703  584   497
#2    1902 3804  364   281
#3    1903 3806  684   259
#4    1904 1904  339   260
#5    1905 1905   42    24
#6    1906 1906   45   150
#7    1910 3820   83    78
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, since you're using the formula method in your "solution", why not use it in the actual solution?

Use `.` to specify "all other variables".

Also, with the `formula` method, `NA` values are treated differently. You need to specify `na.rm` for the `sum` function, and `na.pass` for `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(. ~ Year, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action="na.pass")
#   Year Find Found
# 1 1901  584   497
# 2 1902  364   281
# 3 1903  684   259
# 4 1904  339   260
# 5 1905   42    24
# 6 1906   45   150
# 7 1910   83    78
```

---

For variety (and for some straightforward syntax), there is, of course, `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by = Year]
#    Year Find Found
# 1: 1901  584   497
# 2: 1902  364   281
# 3: 1903  684   259
# 4: 1904  339   260
# 5: 1906   45   150
# 6: 1905   42    24
# 7: 1910   83    78
```

Comment: Cleaner and less to type.. But you get the different answer and the correct sum is in Simons answer:)

Comment: @user1665355, If you look up `na.action` in R help, you should be able to get a better picture.